# SQL query giving error on Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query to list accounts along with current balance, branch no to which it belongs and the average balance of that branch having a balance more than a average balance of the branch to which the account belongs.

The table name is `acmaster`, columns are `acno`, `currbal`, and `branchno`.

Records:

```
acno currbal branchno
1    1000     2
2    2000     2
3    3000     3
4    2000     3
```

I am expecting result like this:

```
acno  currbal  branchno   AVG(currbal)
2     2000      2           1500
3     3000      3           2500
```

This is my current query:

```
select acno,currbal,branchno,AVG(currbal) abal
from acmaster 
group by branchno as bno
having abal < (select currbal from acmaster group by (select branchno from acmaster where branchno=bno));
```

which gets error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 19
```

Comment: **give me**? Seriously? Even if your English is not good at all, this is still bad.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could edit your question to show a few lines of sample data you are trying to access, plus the full definition of the table (including field types). Also, if you are adding code or other similar text, please use the {} code button on the editor to format the text in a more readable form.

Comment: please the error you get.

Comment: The actual error message would be extremely useful too.

Comment: @mathguy is right, don't use _give me_ It sound like an order.

Comment: oh and regarding the comment from @mathguy - please consider editing the title of your question. "give me..." sounds very demanding, almost aggressive to native English speakers. More polite (as you are seeking assistance) is to say something like "I am looking for a solution..." or "Help me with a solution..."

Comment: Sorry for My mistakes. please help me for my query

Comment: this is Error message : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 19

Comment: Try to remove `branchno as bno` in the `group by`. And why you use `where branchno = bno` in the subquery ? It is the same column no ?

Comment: Have to find a balance which have more than average balance of particular branch for that check for that

Comment: @Harshmodi : I understand that you are probably using SQL for the first time.  Whenever you expect us to help you with a query , do post a sample of the data (rows,columns)  that you expect to see. Not  screenshots/ cropped images. Only pure text formatted using `{}`

Comment: please help me for this problem i have upload a sample data and expected result . thank you.

Comment: @Phil: agreed, though on Stack Overflow, unfortunately "please help me" has become synonymous with begging at the very least, if not also "do it for me". It is better merely to say what one is trying to do, without any filler/chatty material.

Comment: @halfer - fair enough. I suppose I was trying to temper what I considered an initial unhelpful response from a native speaker. A little coaching rather than sarcasm can assist non native speakers not to piss off those of us who forget that a foreign language is not always as simple as Google Translate. You are right though, I don't want to encourage crap, so a better title would be the pure issue without the request words (as I see it has been edited to). Failed attempt at creating a better place for everybody :( - but I see we've drawn a lot of attention to an otherwise basic question!

Comment: @Phil: fair points, certainly. Begging for speedy or priority treatment seems to be culturally normal in some Middle Eastern countries, and I have not decided how to best deal with it, given the audience nearly always sees it as grasping and rude. A post filtering wizard would help here, but while that is talked about on Meta, it may never get implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error you're getting, as FoxCy mentioned, is the presence of `as bno` in your group-by clause. The error message is trying to help you there: it refers to line 3 column 19, which is the start of that. SQL Developer even underlines it in red to tell you it's wrong, and I imagine other clients will do something similar.

But you also have columns in your select list which are not aggregates and are not in the group-by; you can't refer to the `abal` alias in the same level of query it was defined - you would have to  do `having avg(currbal) > ...` - and by the same token if you added an alias for `branchno` in the select list instead you couldn't then refer to that either.

Your having clause doesn't make much sense though; the subquery you're trying to compare that average against will get multiple rows, and has an invalid subquery in its own group-by clause. At this point it's probably simpler to start again...

A simplistic way to get the result you want is with something like:

```
select a1.acno, a1.currbal, a1.branchno, (
    select avg(a2.currbal)
    from acmaster a2
    where a2.branchno = a1.branchno
    group by a2.branchno
  ) as abal
from acmaster a1
where a1.currbal > (
    select avg(a3.currbal)
    from acmaster a3
    where a3.branchno = a1.branchno
    group by a3.branchno
  );

      ACNO    CURRBAL   BRANCHNO       ABAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2       2000          2       1500
         3       3000          3       2500
```

The same subquery is repeated as a column expression in the select list, and in the where clause, which is messy, repetitive, hard to maintain, and hard to follow.

A slightly better option is to get the average once in an inline view and then filter the results from that:

```
select * from (
  select a1.acno, a1.currbal, a1.branchno, (
    select avg(a2.currbal)
    from acmaster a2
    where a2.branchno = a1.branchno
    group by a2.branchno) as abal
  from acmaster a1
)
where currbal > abal;
```

Notice that you can now refer to the `abal` alias, as it is being used in a different level of query to where it was defined.

Oracle also has analytic/window functions to simplify that even more, so you don't need the subquery; if you do:

```
select a.acno, a.currbal, a.branchno,
  avg(a.currbal) over (partition by a.branchno) as abal
from acmaster a;

      ACNO    CURRBAL   BRANCHNO       ABAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       1000          2       1500
         2       2000          2       1500
         3       3000          3       2500
         4       2000          3       2500
```

you can see the average for every branch against each row again, and can filter that as an inline view instead:

```
select * from (
  select a.acno, a.currbal, a.branchno,
    avg(a.currbal) over (partition by a.branchno) as abal
  from acmaster a
)
where currbal > abal;

      ACNO    CURRBAL   BRANCHNO       ABAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2       2000          2       1500
         3       3000          3       2500
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at this a line at a time:

```
1> select acno,currbal,branchno,AVG(currbal) abal
2> from acmaster 
3> group by branchno as bno 
4> having abal < (select currbal from acmaster group by (select branchno from acmaster where branchno=bno));
```

On line 3, you are trying to alias `branchno as bno` within the group by statement.  You can't do that, at least not in oracle.

On line 1, you reference columns `acno` and `currbal` without any form of aggregate function, but they don't exist in the `group by` clause on line 3.  Either add an aggregate function to each of these columns, or add them to the `group by` clause

In line 4 you try referencing abal from line 1, but in oracle you can't reference column aliases in the having clause, so use the aggregate `AVG(currbal)` instead.  Additionally Oracle does not allow subqueries in the group by clause, however, the gist of what you appear to be doing in line 4 is ensuring that `AVG(currbal)` is less than some currbal value for that branch, perhaps the `MAX(currbal)`?

Putting it all together this provides the answer you are looking for, though I'm not certain you even need the having clause, as it would eliminate records where the average balance equals the greatest balance (`branchno`s with a single record or where all records for the `branchno` have the same balance):

```
select max(acno) acno
     , max(currbal) currbal
     , branchno
     , AVG(currbal) abal
from acmaster a
group by branchno
having AVG(currbal) < MAX(currbal)
```